# How to find the item index in an array in ANGULAR JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example lets take an array example

```
$scope.users = ['John','Peter'];
```

How to get the index of John ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: zero code from your side ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.users.indexOf('John')
```

This is not angular specific. This is a JS array method.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your view html `{{users.indexOf('John')}}`    or  in your controller use $scope.users.indexOf('John')

Answer (score -1):

Use `track by $index`.

E.g. `<p ng-repeat = "user in $scope.users track by $index"></p>`

Then you can determine if it's John:

```
<p ng-repeat = "user in $scope.users track by $index">
  <span ng-if="$scope.users[$index] === 'John'">Here's John at {{$index}}</span>
</p>
```